# java static final in kotlin: Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value

Tags: kotlin, constants

In Java, We can do this:

```
public class TestA {
    public static final boolean flag = true;
    public static final String str = flag ? "A" : "B"; // ok
}
```

But cannot in Kotlin

```
 class TestA {
    companion object {
        const val flag = true
        const val str = if (flag) "A" else "B" //err: Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value

        val str2 = if (flag) "A" else "B" //ok, but not equals [public static final] in Java.
    }
}
```

Tried **@JvmStatic** on non-const **str2**, but decompiled to java code, it's

```
private static final String str2 = "A"
public static final String getStr2() {
      return Companion.getStr2();
   }
```

Problem: kotlin **if-else** equals **?:** in java,but cannnot use for **const** val. need solution for this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In `Kotlin`, `const` keyword should only be used when value is compile time constant. In your case it is not(`const val str = if (flag) "A" else "B"`). You are using if condition to pass value to `str` on a condition that is not compile time constant.

So you just remove `const` keyword and it will work perfectly. Because `val` creates immutable variables same as final in Java. But there is a tradeoff, if `const` is removed. It will under the hood generates unnecessary object and getter for accessing that variable. To solve this issue use `@JvmField` annotation and you are good to go.

To read more go to [Where Should I Keep My Constants in Kotlin?](https://blog.egorand.me/where-do-i-put-my-constants-in-kotlin/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: non-const val with @JvmField will not create getter, it's **public static final**, that what I'm looking for! thx.

Comment: Hey @chandil03,  In a "kotlin-app" project I can use "const val ID = R.layout.xyz" without a problem, but in a "java+kotlin" library project that snippet throws the same error. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: "const keyword should only be used when value is compile time constant" I mean, this is exactly the problem, in my opinion an if with a constant condition and only constant return values **should** be a compile time constant.