# How to assign a value to a constant depending on another constant value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, constants

This would be useful for me because I have a bunch of constants that are different when I test my program locally vs when I run it on the server that it's supposed to run on.

I assumed an if-else expression would work:

```
const val FOO = false
const val BAR = if (FOO) 1L else 2L
```

However, the compiler considers this an error because for some reason, this if-else expression is not considered to be constant even though it really should be in my opinion, just like arithmetic expressions with constant values can also be assigned to constants.

My first question is, why does this not work, and secondly and more importantly, **is there a way to do this?** Or am I just forced to make these fields not constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [specification on constant properties](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#constant-properties), the only expressions that are allowed are:

> Integer literals and string interpolation expressions without evaluated expressions, as well as built-in arithmetic/comparison operations and string concatenation operations on those [...], as well as other constant properties, but it is implementation-defined which other expressions qualify for this;

This means only *some* very specific expressions and functions can be considered constants, and at the moment they are hard-coded in the compiler.

At the moment, the `if` expression is not considered possible to evaluate at compile time. However, there is an [open ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19698/Support-complex-const-val-initializers) to add support for this case. There is also [a more general ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14652) to potentially allow user-defined constant functions, which would widen the possibilities even further.

> is there a way to do this? Or am I just forced to make these fields not constant?

Not to my knowledge, so yes, just remove the `const` and use a simple `val` instead.

Comment: I really like the phrase “*…but it is implementation-defined which other expressions qualify for this*”. That’s how specifications for a programming language should look like. But I think, [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19698/Support-complex-const-val-initializers) is closer to this question.

Comment: Haha I'm picking up an ounce of sarcasm here. But fair enough, this is weird in a spec, though it's not uncommon to see "this thing is unspecified". That said, in this specific case it would be helpful to have an actual list. I think the Kotlin team left it vague on purpose so they can improve on this more easily without changing the spec.

Comment: Oh thanks for the issue link, I wasn't aware of that one, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @Holger I appreciate the sarcasm, that's precisely how I feel about that kind of "specification" too.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, that pretty much cleared it up. I hope the constant functions feature is going to be implemented at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work since `const` members of a class have to be initialized at the compile time. Indeed, `const` is translated to `final` in the java code generated from kotlin and the compile time initialization is needed for `final` members.

The keyword `val` is already giving you an immutable variable, as opposed to `var`, and therefore technically a constant. Hence, you should be fine with just `val` instead of `const val`.

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer doesn't really answer my question as to why it's not possible. As stated in my question, other constant expressions (for example, `A + B` where `A` and `B` are both constants) **can** be assigned to `const val`s. So I don't really see why my example shouldn't work as well.

As for the statement "technically a constant", no, it being immutable doesn't make it a compile time constant, and that's what I was asking for.

Comment: @Nyde If you initialize a constant as `A+B`, where `A` and `B` are constant, the resulting java code contains only the evaluated result rather than `A+B` stored in the constant.
For `if (FOO) 1L else 2L`, the compiler is not trying to simplify the expression (even though sometimes it could), and hence, value not a compile time constant

Comment: @Nyde In case it is helpful and you haven't seen it, here is a related post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482576/java-static-final-in-kotlin-const-val-initializer-should-be-a-constant-value

Comment: @radof you are just retelling what the question already said, Kotlin does not consider `if (FOO) 1L else 2L` a constant. You are not answering the question about *why* it does not consider it a constant.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for feedback! I indeed overlooked that the question was more nuanced, and at a deeper level, answerable only by members of the Kotlin team.